# Bitlocker decryption trouble

Tags: windows, encryption, disk-encryption, bitlocker

today I started the procedure to access a bitlocker encypted data storage hard disk. At first I unlocked it and then I turned off bitlocker.
The turning off took some time, but it ended without any error.

The result is that the hard drive seems unlocked (no lock icon in Devices and Driver section) but the file are encrypted (I suppose), they are coloured in green, so when I try to open it there is an error that say I can't access data.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, BitLocker doesn't change the color to green for files and folders. What does change the color to green is EFS (Encrypting File System), which is not the same thing as BitLocker.

I suspect that those folders and files have been encrypted with EFS.